# Serve more then one angular app on same nodeJs server

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have 2 angular apps one is `web` and other one is `admin`. I used `NodeJS` and `Express` server to serve this app. For the web url is staring with the / (ex: mydomain.com/) and its work fine. Now i want to access admin panel via `mydomain.com/admin` but its show me error in console.

```
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'admin'
```

Note : Both apps ( web and admin ) are separate angular app.

I tried to serve admin interface using proxy_pass in nginx configratio, But it not worked

Here is my routing congigation in NodeJs Server

app.js

```
//Routing
const WEB = require('./routes/web')   
const ADMIN = require('./routes/admin')   

//app.use('/',WEB);
app.use('/admin/',ADMIN);
app.use('/',WEB);
```

/routes/web.js

```
Router.get('*',(req,res) =>{
    // server from angular build using comand ng build
    res.sendFile(path.join(APP_PATH,'build/index.html'));
})
```

/routes/admin.js

```
Router.get('*',(req,res) =>{
     // server from angular build using command ng build
    res.sendFile(path.join(APP_PATH,'admin/index.html'));
})
```

How can I serve two different apps using the same nodeJS server?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
app.use('/',express.static('build'));
app.use('/admin',express.static('admin'));
```

Comment: Thanks @krishna, but when i tried mydomain.com/admin its still redirect on mydomain.com/ with same error

Comment: @KaushikMakwana Its working for me. Have you removed other routers from the app? Try and put those two line above all the routes you have defined.

Comment: Yes, i removed routers and then i tried your solution, but :(

Comment: The file on which you have started the express server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197836/discussion-between-krishna-sapkal-and-kaushik-makwana).

Comment: Did you succeed to serve two distinct angular apps with the same node server? I encounter the same issue. Thanks